# Application errors on Tomcat 10 (servlet-api.jar seems not to be recognized by the deployed application

Tags: jsp, tomcat

My Tomcat 10 home: /u01/tomcat/base/middleware/tomcat10/
My JSP page refers to these modules:

```
java.io.*
java.sql.*
javax.servlet.*
javax.servlet.http.*
org.apache.commons.fileupload.*
org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*
org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*
java.util.List
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload
```

It seems the servlet-api.jar is not recognized by the application.

1. Do I have an incompatibility with libraries ?
2. The servlet-api.jar is the original file from the installation.
3. Do I miss some modules in the JSP file or can they be incompatible with each other ?

Any suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Comment: See [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi): _"Users of Tomcat 10 onwards should be aware that, as a result of the move from Java EE to Jakarta EE as part of the transfer of Java EE to the Eclipse Foundation, the primary package for all implemented APIs has changed from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`. This will almost certainly require code changes..."_

Comment: A write-up: [Transition from Java EE to Jakarta EE](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee).